# How to set customized displayName to a Jenkins pipeline job?

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

One of my customers has some freestyle Jenkins jobs which display `"#${BUILD_NUMBER}|${BRANCH_NAME}"`
In the description or displayName of the jobs using a plugin called "Build Name Setter".

Unfortunately, this plugin works properly only in freestyle jobs.

[image]
I want to achieve the same goal but with a Jenkins pipeline job.

I've tried adding the following line, just after the checkout step:

```
currentBuild.displayName = "#${BUILD_NUMBER}|${BRANCH_NAME}"
```

But I'm getting an error that "BRANCH_NAME" is not set.

I must use the "SCM step" instead of a dedicated plugin because the repository I'm cloning is a TFS-Git repository and it's plugin doesn't have this functionality.

This is a known issue in the behavior of SCM step specifically in pipeline jobs, but I was wondering if any of you found any workaround which I can implement to display this information in the job's page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by doing something very close to what @haschibaschi suggested but in my case I wrote the BRANCH_NAME to a groovy file in the workspace and loaded it into the BRANCH_NAME variable.

```
stage ('Checkout SCM') {
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/feature/*']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], url: 'http://TFS_SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PC_International/_git/project']]])
            bat """
                cd %workspace%
                set branch="git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"
                FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (' %branch% ') DO SET BRANCH_NAME=%%i
                echo %BRANCH_NAME% > BRANCH_NAME.groovy
            """
            BRANCH_NAME = readFile('BRANCH_NAME.groovy')
            currentBuild.displayName = "# ${BUILD_NUMBER} | ${BRANCH_NAME}"
        }
```

Now the relevant information is displayed as the name of the build:
[image]

Comment: How can you accomplish this outside of stage? I have many stages in my pipeline.

Answer (score -3):

Just get the branch name manually and assign it to BRANCH_NAME.

Something like this (didn't verify the code):

```
dir("checkoutdir") {
   BRANCH_NAME = sh (
     script= "git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2'",
     returnStdout: true
   ).trim()
}
echo "branchname: $BRANCH_NAME"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I forgot to mention that it's running on a windows jenkins slave

Answer (score -3):

In a Jenkinsfile, ${env.BRANCH_NAME} should work.

Comment: There is no context here. Where do you set that variable? Can you show examples or screen shots of your work?